# How to check in an interaval if x time has passed since the creation of a channel in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've been having some hard time writing this and I searched a lot for any similar questions but didn't find any.

So I have this Schema:

```js
new mongoose.Schema({
       Guild: String,
       Username: String,
       UserID: String,
       Channel: String,
       Type: String,
       Reason: String,
       Time: Date,
   })
```

And I want to automatically delete the channel after x time of its creation, the `Time` is saved as `<channel>.createdTimestamp`

And here is the condition of the event:

```js
setInterval(async () => {
        hSchema.find().then((data) => {
            if (!data && !data.length) return
            
            data.forEach(async (value) => {
            const user = value.UserID;
            var time = value.Time; // time of the creation of channel
            var res = time.getTime(); // time in ms  

            // check if user is premium
            uSchema.findOne({ User: user}, async (err, userData) => {
                // if user is not premium
                if (!userData) {
                    const destruct = ms('1m'); // time to pass before deleting 
                    var date = res + destruct; 
                if () { // I can't figure out how to check if x time has passed since the creation of channel
                    // Do stuff here
                    const ch = data.Channel;
                    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(ch)
                     channel.delete()
                     value.delete()
                }
            }
            })
        })
    });
    }, ms("10 seconds"));
```

So as I said I just need some help on how to check if x ms has passed to use it in an `if()` statement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Date.now()` to get the current time in milliseconds, then subtract whatever time you need (in milliseconds), and check that versus your created timestamp, if the number is greater it's been more than a minute!

```js
const minuteInMs = 60000;

if (Date.now() - minuteInMs > channel.createdTimestamp) {
  console.log("more than a minute");
} else {
  console.log("less than a minute");
}
```

Comment: Now I feel bad about myself I thought about everything but couldn't think about this, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use moment to subtract the diff in seconds pretty easy.

```
var now = moment(new Date());
var end = moment(discordChannelCreationTimestamp);

var duration = moment.duration(now.diff(end));

var seconds = duration.asSeconds();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I was searching for something else without using moment or other lib